# Чи український "пілотний проект"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Дуже часто на телебаченні чути слова: "*...пілотний проект*". Наскільки мені відомо, це словосполучення походить від англійського "*pilot project*". В офіційно-діловому та науковому стилі, мабуть, доцільно використовувати його. А як щодо розмовного? Чи існує більш український відповідник цього виразу?

Comment: Було б добре пояснити означення „пілотний проєкт“ чи „pilot project“.

Answer (score 1):

Питання в тому, чи в розмовній мові широко використовується маркетинговий термін.

> Пілотні дослідження (методи пробного продажу) – використовують за
>   недостатньої інформації щодо ринкової ситуації. Вони дають змогу
>   здійснити апробацію нової продукції, методів продажу, зібрати
>   маркетингову інформацію та ін. Ці методи не позбавлені ризику зазнати
>   значних збитків.

[Словник Маркетингу](https://sites.google.com/site/marketingdistance/slovnik)

У розмові з друзями, мабуть, краще казати **пробний, тестовий проект** або просто **перший проект**. Хоч це не передає того значення, що маркетологи керують процесом, але дозволить уникнути питання, до чого тут пілоти.